# Why does a varying magnetic field exerts force on a charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

I know that the equation is force=charge*velocity(perpendicular component)*B. But this equation is just for calculating the force. My question is why would even a charged particle experience force on varying magnetic fields? Is there any relation between magnetic and electric fields?

Answer (score 0):

Both electric and magnetic field's forces are mediated by virtual photons.
Real photons have transverse polarization. Virtual photons have longitudinal polarization too. Although virtual photons are off mass shell, their energy momentum four vector is not 0.

It is a question of the observer's frame of reference. One observer might experience, or observe at some point in space a magnetic field, another observer might only observe an electric field.

The field (magnetic or electric) is creating field lines, in terms of virtual photons. These virtual photons mediate the force to the charged particle (let's say electron) that is in the field. The varying magnetic field and the electron are exchanging virtual photons. This is how it is described in math how the varying magnetic field exerts force on the electron.

The reason why you need a varying magnetic field to exert force on the electron, is relativity. Oscillating magnetic fields interfere destructively, so there is no net force on the electron if the magnetic field is not moving.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are very closely related. You've probably heard the word "electromagnetic" before :). In classical (non quantum) physics, all magnetism comes from moving electric charges. That's it. It doesn't quite explain permanent magnets, which involves atoms lining up together, but you need quantum to fully explain that.

You'll learn maxwell's equations eventually and it'll make sense.

Answer (score 0):

To start with, electric and magnetic fields are observables which have been studied over the centuries and various "laws" defined to explain the observations. So the real answer to your question is "because that is what has been observed and it is encapsulated in [Faraday's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Conceptual_descriptions)"

Maxwell came around and described all available electric and magnetic data with a [set of differential equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations#Formulation_in_Gaussian_units_convention) that encompass all these laws, and tied up beautifully in describing light as an electromagnetic consequence.

Still, the mathematical answer is "because of Maxwell's equations"  but the truth is, this is what data tells us and the equations describe and predict new situations.

Then the quantum mechanical revolution came and a  lower level of equations from which Maxwell's equations can emerge can be used to describe  mathematically how these effects are generated at the microscopic level.

The basic answer is that it is an experimental fact and  *"this is the way charged particles behave and this behavior has been encoded with mathematics"*